# Using Zend_Form_Element_Captcha - session has already been started

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to add a Captcha as part of a big application form.

Getting the following error:

```
session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()
```

How can I get around this as behind the scenes it uses:

```
// Process metadata specific only to this namespace.
Zend_Session::start(true); // attempt auto-start (throws exception if strict option set)
```

I instantiate it in the Controller:

```
$this->view->captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
            'captcha' => array(
                'captcha' => 'Figlet',
                'wordLen' => 6,
                'width' => 300,
                'height' => 100,
          )
      )
 );
```

In the View:

```
<?php echo $this->captcha; ?>
```

I can't tamper with current session as it holds a lot of information. Is there a workaround?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read the message of the error. `session has already been started`. So not try to start again.

Comment: Not as easy as that my friend, the session does a LOT and cannot be interfered with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing in this case, try starting your `Zend session` in bootstrap file in below way and set that session object in registry:

```
protected function _initSession() {
    $userSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user_session');
    Zend_Registry::set('userSession', $userSession);
}
```

After this you will be able to get session object anywhere from registry.

```
$userSession = Zend_Registry::get('userSession');
```

Since you will start your `Zend Session` before `session_start()` so it might not produce any error.

Comment: We use an entire library of code that is very procedural and uses session_start() which I know doesn't play well. May have to call it.

Comment: Yes, you can try calling it. But as far as i know it will only get resolved when zend_session will start before session_start()

Comment: Would it not overwrite?

Comment: I think, No because i went through the same problem with Facebook App integration and the solution which i posted in my answer has resolved my issue. Either dont use session_start() or instantiate zend_session before it.

Comment: It appears to have solved the issue, however I will need to do a thorough check to ensure it hasn't caused any regression. Thanks!